# Exact weights for a chemical reaction og Silver and Nitric Acid

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I'm an amateur analog photographer and want to react Nitric Acid (62%) and silver to Silver nitrate. Silver nitrate is the basis for almost all black and white photography.

I'm trying to figure out the correct ratio of silver to nitric acid. The reaction is $$\ce{3Ag(s) +4HNO3(aq) -> 3AgNO3(l) +NO(g) +2H2O (l)}$$

Can I calculate the ratio of silver to acid with the formula $3 \times (\text{molar weight of Ag}) / 4 \times (\text{Molar weight of HNO3}) \times 0.62$ ?

Comment: This is just a bad idea. Molar proportion's your last concern with this reaction.

Comment: I'm perfectly aware of the reaction and it's bi product. Thanks for your concern!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every 3 moles of Ag reacts with 4 moles of Nitric acid. 

Therefore the mass ratio is: 
 $$ \frac{m(Ag)}{m(HNO3)} = \frac{3}{4}\frac{MM(Ag)}{MM(HNO3)} = 1.28 $$

MM is molar mass(g/mol)

Comment: I have to multiply  4 MM(HNO3) by a factor of 0.62 to take the diluted acid into account, right?

Comment: So you want the ratio:  silver mass/volume HNO3 solution?

Comment: Silver mass / mass of dilluted HNO3 preferably.